Https calls not working with Webclient with self signed p12 certificate
I have enabled HTTPS for my Springboot Webflux (using Netty server) microservices by creating a self-signed certificate using keytool
keytool -genkeypair -alias mycert -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore mycert.p12 -validity 3650

I have then placed the certificate in src/main/resources/keystore and added these properties in my application properties file -
#Settings to enable https
# The format used for the keystore. It could be set to JKS in case it is a JKS file
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/mycert.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=mycert
server.ssl.enabled=true

server.ssl.trust-store-password=password

I have 4 microservices and I have used the same certificate and same above config properties for all the 4 services and I see the services are coming up with the HTTPS enabled.
As part of some flows we need to call an endpoint(now https) from one of these services(A) to another service(B) and this is how I have modified the webclient creation logic in service A to account for the https-
@Value("${server.ssl.trust-store-password}")
  private String trustStorePassword;
@Bean
  @Qualifier("serviceBWebClient")
  public WebClient serviceBWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    HttpClient secureCLient = null;
    try {
      LOGGER.info("Creating WebClient bean for service B API calls");
      secureCLient = getSecuredHttpClient();

    } catch(Exception e){
      LOGGER.error("Exception occurred in creating secured web client for service B API call");
    }
    return builder
            .baseUrl("https://localhost:9443/api")
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(null!=secureCLient?secureCLient:getUnsecuredHttpClient()))
            .build();
  }

 private HttpClient getSecuredHttpClient() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Creating secure HttpClient.");
    File file = new ClassPathResource("keystore/mycert.p12").getFile();

    return HttpClient.create().secure(spec -> {
      try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(file.getPath())), trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        // Set up key manager factory to use key-store
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        spec.sslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
                .build());
      }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error occurred");
      }
    });

But when trying to make the api call this is the exception that keeps coming
07-08-2024 19:19:33.018 [reactor-http-nio-4] [T:66b37b6c082adc435ef2af5d6cfda4f9,S:5ef2af5d6cfda4f9] INFO  c.a.t.s.d.ServiceImpl - Initiate Service B API call..
07-08-2024 19:19:33.123 [reactor-http-nio-4] [T:,S:] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://localhost:9443/api [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4568)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:205)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:140)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:229)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:279)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:140)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.maybeOnError(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:327)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:212)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:118)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:118)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.drain(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:476)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor$EmitterInner.drainParent(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:620)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PubSubInner.request(FluxPublish.java:874)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.request(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:163)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.request(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:163)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:337)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.request(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:163)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$DeferredSubscription.request(Operators.java:1743)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:196)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:140)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:205)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:311)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:140)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:205)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:222)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:476)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:148)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:424)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:92)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$1.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:145)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:143)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.exceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:231)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317)
        at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler.userEventTriggered(SslProvider.java:864)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:398)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:376)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleUnwrapThrowable(SslHandler.java:1362)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1343)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1387)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:530)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:469)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1407)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:918)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1351)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1226)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1169)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1651)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1497)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1338)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1387)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:530)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:469)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1407)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:918)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1329)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
07-08-2024 19:19:33.129 [reactor-http-nio-4] [T:,S:] WARN  r.n.http.client.HttpClientConnect - [7c2f3ab2, L:/127.0.0.1:51487 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9443] The connection observed an error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1351)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1226)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1169)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1651)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1497)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1338)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1387)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:530)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:469)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1407)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:918)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1329)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
07-08-2024 19:19:33.135 [reactor-http-nio-4] [T:,S:] WARN  r.n.http.client.HttpClientConnect - [7c2f3ab2, L:/127.0.0.1:51487 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9443] The connection observed an error
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:500)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1407)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:918)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1351)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1226)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1169)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1651)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1497)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1338)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1387)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:530)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:469)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1329)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 36 common frames omitted


I was following this link for this implementation https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate and I see something similar RestTemplate implementation -
RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
      .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getURL(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
      .build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
      .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
      .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = 
      new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(factory);
}

Can someone please point out if what I am doing is the standard way of achieving https for all my service
EDIT1
Finally got this working with these changes -

need one public crt exported from the p12 certificate -

keytool -exportcert -rfc -keystore tob.p12 -storetype PKCS12  -alias mycert -file mycert-pub.crt

2)Make sure the name provided when creating the p12 certificate is "localhost" as HTTPS enables hostname matching, this means we need different certificates for different envs
3)changes to the getSecuredHttpClient method -
private HttpClient getSecuredHttpClient() throws IOException {
    LOGGER.info("Creating secure Service B HttpClient.");

    SslContext context = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .trustManager(new ClassPathResource("mycert-pub.crt", this.getClass().getClassLoader()).getInputStream())
            .build();

    return HttpClient
            .create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, ApplicationConstants.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(ApplicationConstants.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS));
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(ApplicationConstants.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS))
            .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec
                    .sslContext(context));
  }

notice new ClassPathResource("mycert-pub.crt",this.getClass().getClassLoader()) i had not added ".getClassLoader()" which was not able to get the cert file
After these changes i am able to make the https call between the services A and B.

i am note sure adding it to the properties is enough, have you tried adding it to jdk's keysore? e.g. $JDK_HOME/bin/keytool -importcert -file /path/to/certificate.cert -alias my-alias -keystore $JDK_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

i have noticed some answers where it is mentioned to use InsecureTrustManagerFactory , but as I understand it, this is not recommended as it defeats the purpose of having https in the first place

no, that is correct, InsecureTrustManagerFactory is just something to consider for local development, but definetely not prod

@JAsgarov yeah that is one option to import the cert in my JVM's cacert store, but in production we will not have the option to import the cert in the deployment server this way, so ideally we ship all the required keystore files along with the application itself or place a custom jks in the server and use it to create http client

You could add it (also in prod) programatically in java code during startup as an idea. Check if not present then add

i was able to fix the error with my implementation, let me update my answer with the solution, also the answer by Scott is a much cleaner solution, and also working fine for me, so accepted the answer

If you are using Spring Boot 3.1 or later, you can greatly simplify this configuration using the SSL Bundles feature.
For the client, set the truststore properties in an SSL bundle in application.properties:
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.client.truststore.type=PKCS12
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.client.truststore.location=classpath:keystore/mycert.p12
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.client.truststore.password=password
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.client.key.alias=mycert

Then configure the WebClient to use the bundle as shown in the documentation:
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("serviceBWebClient")
  public WebClient serviceBWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder, WebClientSsl ssl) {
    return builder
            .baseUrl("https://localhost:9443/api")
            .apply(ssl.fromBundle("client"))
            .build();
  }

For consistency with the client side, you can change the web server application.properties in your example to this:
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.server.keystore.type=PKCS12
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.server.keystore.location=classpath:keystore/mycert.p12
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.server.keystore.password=password
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.server.key.alias=mycert

server.ssl.bundle=server


i was able to fix my implementation as well, but I like this approach better because its much cleaner and helps us avoid code for reading the cert file and creating our custom ssl context
